# STM32 message filtering didn't work as expected

Tags: c, filter, stm32, stm32cubeide

So, I'm trying to read my TESEO LIV3FL GNSS module using I2C communication and STM32 Nucleo-WL55JC1. I can print the sensor log to my serial monitor perfectly. Here's the screenshot

```
$GNGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,99.0,99.0,99.0*1E
$GPGLL,0745.76471,S,11023.30874,E,040509.000,V,N*58
$PSTMCPU,27.96,-1,98*49
$GPRMC,040510.000,V,0745.76471,S,11023.30874,E,,,061222,,,N*62
$GPGGA,040510.000,0745.76471,S,11023.30874,E,0,00,99.0,175.23,M,0.0,M,,*7E
$GPVTG,,T,,M,,N,,K,N*2C
$GNGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,99.0,99.0,99.0*1E
$GNGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,99.0,99.0,99.0*1E
$GPGLL,0745.76471,S,11023.30874,E,040510.000,V,N*50
$PSTMCPU,15.14,-1,98*42
.76471,S,11023.30874,E,,,061222,,,N*6A
$GPGGA,040509.000,0745.76471,S,11023.30874,E,0,00,99.0,175.23,M,0.0,M,,*76
$GPVTG,,T,,M,,N,,K,N*2C
$GNGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,99.0,99.0,99.0*1E
$GNGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,99.0,99.0,99.0*1E
$GPGLL,0745.76471,S,11023.30874,E,040509.000,V,N*58
$PSTMCPU,27.96,-1,98*49
$GPRMC,040510.000,V,0745.76471,S,11023.30874,E,,,061222,,,N*62
$GPGGA,040510.000,0745.76471,S,11023.30874,E,0,00,99.0,175.23,M,0.0,M,,*7E
$GPVTG,,T,,M,,N,,K,N*2C
$GNGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,99.0,99.0,99.0*1E
$GNGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,99.0,99.0,99.0*1E
$GPGLL,0745.76471,S,11023.30874,E,040510.000,V,N*50
```

However, when I tried to filter only GPGGA message only it filtered the wrong message. Here's the serial monitor output

```
$GNGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,9GPGGA,040509.000,0745.76471,S,11023.30874,E,0,00,99.0,175.0,99.0,99.0*1E6
$GNGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,9GPGGA,040509.000,0745.76471,S,11023.30874,E,0,00,99.0,175.0,99.0,99.0*1E6
```

Where it should be

```
GPGGA,040509.000,0745.76471,S,11023.30874,E,0,00,99.0,175.0,99.0,99.0*1E6
GPGGA,040509.000,0745.76471,S,11023.30874,E,0,00,99.0,175.0,99.0,99.0*1E6
```

Here's my variable declaration

```
uint8_t receivedData[1000];
uint8_t filteredMessage[1000];

char buff[1000];
char *ptr;

const char desiredNMEA[] = "$GPGGA";
```

And my infinite loop

```
  while (1)
  {
      // Start reading data
      ret = HAL_I2C_IsDeviceReady(&hi2c1, TESEO_LIV3FL_ADDRESS, 2, 10);

      if (ret != HAL_OK) {
          sprintf((char*)buff, "Device is not ready \r\n");
      } else {
          ret = HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(&hi2c1, TESEO_LIV3FL_ADDRESS, receivedData, sizeof(receivedData), HAL_MAX_DELAY);

          if (ret != HAL_OK) {
              sprintf((char*)buff, "Error Rx \r\n");
          }
      }

      ptr = strstr((char*)receivedData, desiredNMEA);

      if(ptr) {
          int position = ptr - (char*)receivedData;

          while((char*)receivedData[position] != '\n') {
              filteredMessage[position] = filteredMessage[position];
              position++;
          }

          filteredMessage[position] = '\0';

          HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, filteredMessage, strlen((char*)filteredMessage), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
          HAL_Delay(500);
      }

    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
```

Here's for the [full](https://pastebin.com/M9XCqeL2) code since it's too long. Any idea where did I go wrong?

**Edit #1**

When I unplugged and then plugged it again the data just become haywire
[image]

**Edit #2**

Implemented Flexz's solution. The data still corrupted and truncated but we're getting somewhere

```
⸮⸮榦x>ZGPGGA,055223.070,0745.75895,S,11GPGGA,055232.000,0745.75895,S,11GPGGA,055237.000,0745.75895,S,11023.30466,E,0,00,99.0,167.95,M,0.0,M,,*7C
'⸮⸮<⸮
⸮b⸮
```

Answer (score 1):

Stm32 has nothing to do here, it's a bug in your code.

```
          while((char*)receivedData[position] != '\n') {
              filteredMessage[position] = filteredMessage[position];
              position++;
          }
```

Assigning the unassigned variable to itself? Of course it doesn't work.

And `HAL_UART_Transmit` is a blocking call, there is no reason to insert a delay after it.

Comment: whoops didn't realised that! changed the wrong line, but still got a corrupted message (See edited)

Answer (score 1):

The next problem is that you insert the part you want into the output buffer at the same position that it was at in the unfiltered buffer.  You need to insert it into the output buffer starting at zero.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is my first time using STM32 and its IDE. Do you have any reference how to insert the output buffer starting in zero? In many tutorials I've seen, people just slap the `HAL_UART_Transmit()`